# How old are Mom and her children?

Tags: futurama

In one of the earlier episodes the Professor is going to be taken away by the Reapers to go to a retirement community in space at the age of 150(?).  And from one of the movies we learn that the youngest of Mom's sons is her love child with the Professor. How old are Mom's children and how old is Mom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their exact ages are never given. The best estimates are as follows:

- [Mom](http://theinfosphere.org/Mom): born sometime before 2881, when the Professor began working for her company.
- [Her sons](http://theinfosphere.org/Mom%27s_sons) ([Walt](http://theinfosphere.org/Walt), [Larry](http://theinfosphere.org/Larry), and [Igner](http://theinfosphere.org/Igner)): Based on the movie [*Bender's Game*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Game), they would appear to be [in their thirties](http://theinfosphere.org/Mom%27s_sons#Age), with Walt and Larry being slightly older than Igner since they were around when Professor Farnsworth fathered him around the time he discovered dark matter.

Answer (score 1):

Larry is 37 at the time of Bender's Game. We can assume Walt is no older than 2 years older than Larry, based on the scene of them as kids. I am guessing Igner is at least 4 years younger than Larry, putting them all in their 30s (maybe 20s for Igner)

Comment: What does this add that the existing answer does not already cover?

Comment: It does provide more specific detail, and the rationale for the estimated ages.

Comment: But how old is Mom, and where are your sources, young man!?